# How does swift JSONEncoder() encode swift NSDate/ Data types?

Tags: node.js, swift, websocket, binary, jsonencoder

In swift how does the JSOnEncoder() encode Data data types?

Here is my struct that i am encoding

```
    struct VoiceQueryRequest: Codable {
          var type:String = "voiceQuery"
          var audioOutput:Data = Data()
    }
```

Im using websockets to send the encoded json object to a node server. Im using URLSessionWebSocketTask.Message.data to create the websockets message.

I need to understand how the audioOutput: Data propertie is encoded so that i can decode the object on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSONEncoder` has a [`dataEncodingStrategy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonencoder/2895381-dataencodingstrategy) property that determines how `Data` properties are encoded.  The default is to encode it as a base 64 string.